Is there a way to mount Azure File Share on Web App via Key Vault Reference using Bicep?
Here is the module I am currently using:
// Parameters for the module
param appName string // Name of the existing Web App
param storageAccountName string // Name of the existing Storage Account

// Non-editable variables
var shareName = 'shared'
var mountPath = '/mounts/shared'

// Reference to the existing Web App
resource webApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2023-12-01' existing = {
name: appName
}

// Reference to the existing storage account
resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2019-06-01' existing = {
  name: storageAccountName
}

resource storageSetting 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2021-01-15' = {
  name: 'azurestorageaccounts'
  parent: webApp
  properties: {
    '${shareName}': {
      type: 'AzureFiles'
      shareName: shareName
      mountPath: mountPath
      accountName: storageAccount.name
      accessKey: storageAccount.listKeys().keys[0].value
    }
  }
}

However, I'd like to use key vault reference like how it can be manually done in the Azure portal.
Is this possible?

Try replacing accessKey with [@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName={vaultName};SecretName={secretName}) this will make sure webapp will have access to keyvault @jobatthemall

@VinayB I tried that, but in the storage mount section it just shows this in the access key section: [@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=kvsndbx010;SecretName=storage-account-key)] Like it's not referencing it actually, rather just inserted the string. Go to edit your mount on the web app, then click advanced and you'll see there is an option for key vault reference vs manual input. https://imgur.com/a/JpQqOxm

@jobatthemall, let me know if you need more details

@Thomas I have another question posted if you know of a way to help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79215607/how-to-bind-a-custom-domain-to-an-azure-web-app-with-bicep-using-only-asuid-txt

Assuming that the connection string is already stored in key vault and that your app service has secret read permission over the key vault.

You need a new app setting (key vault reference) pointing to the connectionstring your key vault.

resource webApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2023-12-01' = {
  name: appName
  ...
  properties: {
    ...
    siteConfig: {
       appSettings: [
          {
            name: 'StorageconnectionString'
            value: '@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=<key vault name>;SecretName=<name of the connectionstring secret>)'
          }
          ...
       ]
    }
  }
}


Then reference the app setting when creating the file share

resource storageSetting 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2021-01-15' = {
  name: 'azurestorageaccounts'
  parent: webApp
  properties: {
    '${shareName}': {
      type: 'AzureFiles'
      shareName: shareName
      mountPath: mountPath
      accountName: storageAccount.name
      accessKey: '@AppSettingRef(StorageconnectionString)'
    }
  }
}


Thank you! That is exactly what I was looking to do.


Mounting Azure File Share on Web App via Key Vault Reference using Bicep

To achieve this requirement, you need to store the storage account as secret and grant necessary permission for the webapp to access the keyvault and make sure to use of @Microsoft.KeyVault
Deployment:
param appName string = 'testvksb' 
param storageAccountName string = 'tesstvaksbbsamp' 
param keyVaultName string = 'testkeyavuktsva' 
param secretName string = 'testsecret' 


var shareName = 'shared'
var mountPath = '/mounts/shared'


resource webApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2023-12-01' existing = {
  name: appName
}


resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2019-06-01' existing = {
  name: storageAccountName
}


resource keyVault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2021-06-01' existing = {
  name: keyVaultName
}


resource storageSetting 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2021-01-15' = {
  name: 'azurestorageaccounts'
  parent: webApp
  properties: {
    '${shareName}': {
      type: 'AzureFiles'
      shareName: shareName
      mountPath: mountPath
      accountName: storageAccount.name
      accessKey: '[@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=${keyVaultName};SecretName=${secretName})]'
    }
  }
}

Deployment:


refer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-connect-to-azure-storage?tabs=basic%2Cportal&pivots=container-linux

Hi Vinay, I tried that, but in the storage mount section it just shows this in the access key section: [@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=kvsndbx010;SecretName=storage-account-key)]
Like it's not referencing it actually, rather just inserted the string. Go to edit your mount on the web app, then click advanced and you'll see there is an option for key vault reference vs manual input.

https://imgur.com/a/JpQqOxm
