How to bind a custom domain to an Azure Web App with Bicep using only ASUID TXT record?
I have been trying to use the following below to bind a custom domain to an existing Azure web app, the problem is I need to only use asuid TXT record, as the CNAME for the custom domain is pointing to the application gateway vip...
// Editable parameters
param customDomainName string
param appName string
param appServicePlanName string
param location string = resourceGroup().location

// Reference to the existing web app
resource webApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2023-12-01' existing = {
  name: appName
}

resource appServicePlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2023-12-01' existing = {
  name: appServicePlanName
}

// Step 1: Add the custom domain (hostname binding) to the web app
resource customDomainBinding 'Microsoft.Web/sites/hostNameBindings@2022-03-01' = {
  parent: webApp
  name: customDomainName
  properties: {
    hostNameType: 'Verified'
  }
}

// Step 2: Create a managed certificate for the custom domain
resource certificates 'Microsoft.Web/certificates@2022-03-01' = {
  name: '${customDomainName}-managed-cert'
  location: location
  properties: {
    canonicalName: customDomainName
    serverFarmId: appServicePlan.id
  }
}

// Step 3: Update the SSL state for the custom domain (SSL binding)
// Only bind SSL once, do not create a separate binding
resource customDomainSsl 'Microsoft.Web/sites/hostNameBindings@2022-03-01' = {
  parent: webApp
  name: customDomainName // This should be the same as above
  properties: {
    hostNameType: 'Verified'
    sslState: 'SniEnabled'
    thumbprint: certificates.properties.thumbprint
    customHostNameDnsRecordType: 'CName'
  }
}

I then get this, because as I mentioned the CNAME is pointed to the app gateway vip
Hostname not eligible for App Service Managed Certificates creation. Ensure that your domain has an active CNAME record which is set to .azurewebsites.net etc

Another route I've tried is referencing a cert in a key vault, but have not been successful with the below
// Editable parameters
param subIdOfCertKeyVault string
param certKeyVaultResourceGroup string
param customDomainName string
param appName string
param certKeyVaultName string
param certificateSecretName string

// Reference to the existing web app
resource webApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2023-12-01' existing = {
  name: appName
}

// Reference Key Vault
resource keyVault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2023-07-01' existing = {
  name: certKeyVaultName
  scope: resourceGroup(subIdOfCertKeyVault, certKeyVaultResourceGroup)
}

// Reference the secret in Key Vault
resource keyVaultSecret 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets@2023-07-01' existing = {
  parent: keyVault
  name: certificateSecretName
}

// Directly bind the certificate to the hostname
resource customDomainSsl 'Microsoft.Web/sites/hostNameBindings@2022-03-01' = {
  parent: webApp
  name: customDomainName
  properties: {
    hostNameType: 'Verified'
    sslState: 'SniEnabled'
    thumbprint: keyVaultSecret.properties.secretUri
  }
}

This Azure CLI below works with only using a TXT record and a managed cert...
### Set the variables ###
$SubscriptionIDofWebApp = '' # Subscription ID of where the lms web app will be created
$Company = ''
$Environment = '' # lower or prod
$SubEnvironment = '' # dev, uat, qa, etc. Note: if prod, enter prod
$Location = '' # Region where the subscription is
$Record = ''

    # Set Subscription for Web App
    Write-Host 'Setting the subscription of the web app...'
    az account set --subscription $SubscriptionIDofWebApp
        
    # Set Thumbprint Variable
    Write-Host 'Creating the variable for the thumbprint...'
    $Thumbprint = az webapp config ssl list --resource-group "rg-$Company-$Environment-app-$Location-001" --query "[].thumbprint" --output tsv
    
    # Bind the SSL Cert
    Write-Host 'Binding the SSL Cert...'
    az webapp config ssl bind --resource-group "rg-$Company-$Environment-app-$Location-001" --name "app-$Company-$SubEnvironment-lms-$Location-001" --certificate-thumbprint "$Thumbprint" --ssl-type SNI

Please let me know if you know the proper, best way to do this with BICEP when only a TXT record can be used for validation, not CNAME.

This ended up being the solution:
// Editable parameters
param customDomainName string
param appName string
param appServicePlanName string
param location string
param subIdOfCertKeyVault string
param certKeyVaultResourceGroup string
param certKeyVaultName string
param certificateSecretName string

// Reference to the existing web app
resource webApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2024-04-01' existing = {
  name: appName
}
resource appServicePlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2024-04-01' existing = {
  name: appServicePlanName
}
resource certKeyVault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2023-07-01' existing = {
  name: certKeyVaultName
  scope: resourceGroup(subIdOfCertKeyVault, certKeyVaultResourceGroup)
}

// Create a managed certificate for the custom domain
resource certificate 'Microsoft.Web/certificates@2023-12-01' = {
  name: customDomainName
  location: location
  properties: {
    keyVaultId: certKeyVault.id
    keyVaultSecretName: certificateSecretName
    serverFarmId: appServicePlan.id
  }
}

// Update the SSL state for the custom domain (SSL binding)
// Only bind SSL once, do not create a separate binding
resource customDomainSsl 'Microsoft.Web/sites/hostNameBindings@2023-12-01' = {
  parent: webApp
  name: customDomainName // This should be the same as above
  properties: {
    hostNameType: 'Verified'
    sslState: 'SniEnabled'
    thumbprint: certificate.properties.thumbprint
  }
}


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
